# Site made in DW almost done; can't get it to center with wrapper

Tags: centering

I'm re-doing a multi-page website I made with Dreamweaver over a decade ago for my Stained glass business. It is old code and I am a do it yourself amateur as a web-site maker, but the site pages look good on browsers, links work, text size ok, images and background graphic look good to me. **I'm trying to get one of the pages to center in browser windows** so I can do that with all pages. The site uses absolute position to arrange the photo images of leaded-windows and some text boxes. It uses a table for reference links to different gallery and information areas of the site. It uses the built-in Dreamweaver CSS text for style rules.

I  followed a Dreamweaver tutorial on centering the page which basically goes like this:

```
 </head> 

   <body>

  <div id ="wrapper">

      < web page information/code/ html stuff>

    </div>

    </body>

       </html>
```

The CSS goes like this

```
    <style type="text css">

       <!-- 

         #wrapper{ 

     margin: 0 auto; 

      width: 1240px; 

     }
```

This code looks pretty standard from my inquiries but it is not making the page center in a browser window; the page still hugs the left side. The Dreamweaver community forum, dominated by Nancy O'Shea refuses to help unless I learn the Bootstrap code, and I am not ready for that, having spent many, many hours cleaning up errors on current code and changing some style issues and adding new pages etc. I don't know what is causing the problem: absolute positioning?, the table?, my background graphic gif? If a helpful person knows why my attempt to center is failing It would mean a lot to me. If it would help I will post the entire block of code for the page.

<<

Comment: you can ignore all the ***. I was just trying to bold the key parts.